# Error, statement invalid. simple model method not functioning correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, parameters, model, associations

I am trying to create an object which doesn't seem to be accessing its associated models information correctly. What is wrong with my syntax and whats best practice in this situation? Below is my code and error:

### controller

```
class LineItemsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @line_item = LineItem.new
  end
  def create
    @line_item = LineItem.create!(params[:line_item].merge(:cart => current_cart))
    @line_item.update_attributes!(:unit_price => @line_item.item_price)
    redirect_to current_cart_url
  end
end
```

### model

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cart_id, :product_id, :quantity, :unit_price, :product, :cart, :color_id, :size_id, :extra_id, :color, :size, :extra
  belongs_to :cart
  belongs_to :product
  has_one :color
  has_one :size
  has_one :extra
  validates :quantity, :presence => true
  def item_price
    if size.price.nil? || size.price == 0
      if  extra.price.nil? || extra.price ==0
        product.price
      else
        product.price + extra.price
      end
    else
      if extra.price.nil? || extra.price == 0
        product.price + size.price
      else
        product.price + size.price + extra.price
      end
    end
  end
  def full_price
          unit_price * quantity
  end
end
```

### error

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid at /line_items
PG::Error: ERROR:  column sizes.line_item_id does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes"  WHERE "sizes"."line_item_id"...
                                              ^
: SELECT  "sizes".* FROM "sizes"  WHERE "sizes"."line_item_id" = 4 LIMIT 1

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#log
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb, line 285
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#log
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb, line 275
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#exec_query
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb, line 659
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#select
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb, line 1256
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#select_all
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb, line 18
block in ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#select_all
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb, line 61
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#cache_sql
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb, line 75
ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter#select_all
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb, line 61
block in Size.find_by_sql
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/querying.rb, line 38
Size.logging_query_plan
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/explain.rb, line 41
Size.find_by_sql
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/querying.rb, line 37
ActiveRecord::Relation#exec_queries
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 171
block in ActiveRecord::Relation#to_a
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 160
ActiveRecord::Relation#logging_query_plan
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/explain.rb, line 34
ActiveRecord::Relation#to_a
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation.rb, line 159
ActiveRecord::Relation#find_first
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 380
ActiveRecord::Relation#first
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb, line 122
ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation#find_target
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb, line 42
ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation#load_target
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb, line 145
ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation#reload
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/association.rb, line 55
ActiveRecord::Associations::HasOneAssociation#reader
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/singular_association.rb, line 9
block in LineItem#product
activerecord (3.2.13) lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb, line 44
LineItem#item_price
app/models/line_item.rb, line 10
LineItemsController#create
app/controllers/line_items_controller.rb, line 7
```

Any insight is appreciated

Comment: the error says `ERROR:  column sizes.line_item_id does not exist` - try running this `psql YOUR_DB_NAME -c "\d sizes"` it will display all information on your sizes table, guessing it does not have that column? maybe need to run db:migrate or there is error in column naming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you run `rake db:migrate` ?

Edit::
Okay looking at the stack trace, we have `line_items_controller.rb, line 7` `@line_item.item_price` , which in turn calls `line_item.rb, line 10`, which is `if size.price.nil? || size.price == 0`

So the error is in calling `size`.  What does `Size.find_by_id(4)` give you in console?

Edit::
Also I think your association is incorrect - I would think the `sizes` table should not have a `line_item_id` column, instead the `line_items` table should have a `size_id` column.  In which case, you want `belongs_to :size`.

Comment: It would appear size is nil

Comment: from rails console:    #<LineItem id: 4, unit_price: nil, product_id: 1, cart_id: 1, color_id: 1, size_id: 4, extra_id: nil, quantity: 2, created_at: "2013-06-25 01:53:21", updated_at: "2013-06-25 01:53:21">